# В чём назначение классов и как их использовать?

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

Я совсем не понимаю что такое классы и как их можно использовать в коде. Искал в инете - ничего не понял, т.к. только учусь. Прошу объяснить простым языком что это такое и по возможности привести примеры.

Comment: Нужно в сходить библиотеку, взять книжку, а лучше две или пять, и читать до понимания. Вряд ли тут кто-то будет расписывать то, что уже стопицот раз описано, да ещё с примерами, которых в разных местах тысячи.

Comment: Почитайте про ООП, питон тут ни при чём

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: посмотрите. первые 45 минут можно пролистать,там реклама https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=84fkaFMqYJs&t=3004s

Comment: https://python-scripts.com/object-oriented-programming-in-python

Answer (score 2):

[source](https://python-scripts.com/object-oriented-programming-in-python):

> **Объект** — это что-либо, у чего есть какие-либо характеристики и то, что может выполнить какую-либо функцию.

> **Класс** в объектно-ориентированном программировании выступает в роли чертежа для объекта. Класс можно рассматривать как карту дома. Вы можете понять, как выглядит дом, просто взглянув на его карту.

Answer (score -2):

Класс - это как чертеж, в рамках которого размещаются объекты и методы.
Своего рода, просто разметка кода.